# Shape drawable in xml same code programatically

Tags: android, android-drawable, kotlin, xml-drawable

I have the following xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
  <solid android:color="@color/coral_seconds"/>

  <size
      android:height="24dp"
      android:width="24dp"/>
</shape>
```

How to make this xml as a programatical `Drawable` oject?

I tried without success (Kotlin):

```
val circle = ShapeDrawable(OvalShape())

circle.paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, resId)
circle.paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL;
```

Answer can be in Java, I don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the size can simply be set by the `intrinsicDIMEN` values like:

```
val circle = ShapeDrawable(OvalShape())

circle.intrinsicHeight = dpi24
circle.intrinsicWidth = dpi24

circle.paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, resId)
circle.paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL;
```